# Count the repetitions under conditions

Tags: python, pandas

hello first of all I present you my data:

| registered | Name | Daughter of |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 7D | Sara | 8A |
| 8A | Rosa | Na |
| 4D | Jess | 8A |
| 6B | Veronica | Na |
| 8L | Sophia | 6B |
| 7D | Sara | 8A |

Knowing that the data can be repeated (and it is wanted for my case I would like to keep them).

What I would like to do is a column that tells me how many children each person has (obviously there will be na for those who don't have children but that's okay), so that it looks like this:

| registered | Name | Daughter of | children |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7D | Sara | 8A | Na |
| 8A | Rosa | Na | 2 |
| 4D | Jess | 8A | Na |
| 6B | Veronica | Na | 1 |
| 8L | Sophia | 6B | Na |
| 7D | Sara | 8A | Na |

How can i proceed ?

WARNING !!! I didn't put this in my example but in my data the lines repeat and I don't have to remove them imagine that there is another line from Sara that contains the same information

Comment: in what form is the original data? The quickest way would be to split the columns into separate lists and do a `daughterof_column_list.count(registered_listelement)`. [w3 Docs](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_list_count.asp)

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention that the data is in the form of pandas dataframe

Comment: In order to simplify solutions (such as getting the solution by JMA to work), your data should be "NA" rather than "Na" (i.e. "NA" is interpreted by Pandas for missing values not Na).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an auxiliar DataFrame grouped by the "number of children" of every "registered", to later merge it with your original one. It would be as it follows:

```
import pandas as pd

# Setting the data
all_rows = [["7D","Sara","8A"],
            ["8A","Rosa","Na"],
            ["4D","Jess","8A"],
            ["6B","Veronica","Na"],
            ["8L","Sophia","6B"],
            ["7N","iria","Na"],
            ["7D","Sara","8A"],
            ["8A","Rosa","Na"]] 

df = pd.DataFrame(all_rows, columns=["registered","name","daughter_of"])

# Df aux
df_grouped = df.drop_duplicates().groupby(["daughter_of"])["daughter_of"].count().reset_index(name="children")

# Renaming columns so the join is made correctly
df_grouped.columns = ["registered", "children"]

# Joining
df = pd.merge(df,df_grouped[df_grouped["registered"]!="Na"],on=["registered"],how='left')
```

This are the outputs that I am receiving.

```
  registered      name daughter_of  children
0         7D      Sara          8A       NaN
1         8A      Rosa          Na       2.0
2         4D      Jess          8A       NaN
3         6B  Veronica          Na       1.0
4         8L    Sophia          6B       NaN
5         7N      iria          Na       NaN
6         7D      Sara          8A       NaN
7         8A      Rosa          Na       2.0
```

The rows count are only taken into account once by the field "registered".

Comment: sorry your code works but it doesn't really represent what I want, it recovers the repeats of the daughter of column, which is not wrong the problem is that I have lines that repeat that I must absolutely keep, see it as if we add another line with the same information about Sara

Comment: I think I understand now what you mean. I have added a drop_duplicates() statement in the aux dataframe that is used to join. I believe that with the edit it should work as expected.

Comment: No this is not exactly what I want, but you but in code the continuation of my base and what I want then more and more clear.

all_rows = [["7D","Sara","8A"],
["8A","Rosa","Na"],
["4D","Jess","8A"],
["6B","Veronica","Na"],
["8L","Sophia","6B"],
["7N","iria","Na"],
["7D","Sara","8A"]
["8A","Rosa","Na"]]

The final Data will be :
 [["7D","Sara","8A","Na"],
["8A","Rosa","Na",2],
["4D","Jess","8A","Na"],
["6B","Veronica","Na",1],
["8L","Sophia","6B","Na"],
["7N","iria","Na","Na"],
["7D","Sara","8A","Na"]
["8A","Rosa","Na",2]]

Comment: I get the same data that you showed by running my script, with the same inputs. The "children" field will only take into account the "registered" column as primary_key

Comment: yes I would not explain for some cases I have 67 and 30 children, your code seems however the good one

Answer (score 1):

If your original data is stored in a Pandas DataFrame (`df`) you can use:

```py
df = df.replace('Na', pd.NA)
df['children'] = df['registered'].map(df.drop_duplicates(subset='registered')['Daughter of'].value_counts().to_dict())
```

Comment: sorry your code works but it doesn't really represent what I want, it recovers the repeats of the daughter of column, which is not wrong the problem is that I have lines that repeat that I must absolutely keep, see it as if we add another line with the same information about Sara

Comment: I think that this solution does keep the repeated rows.

Comment: Yes she keeps but the problem is that she takes them into account, put the same Sara in my first table of example it is however the same person it is going to count that it makes a child more whereas not it is necessary that the person is different

Comment: Ok I see. I have edited my answer. Now it should be fine.

Comment: No it still doesn't work but the code is sound, it's just that in my database it happens that some lines are repeated but it's entirely intentional and I have to leave them like that, your code repeats the lines of the same mother and gives me numbers too big for some mothers, I don't want the code to delete the lines that repeat (let's say there are x times the same sara and x times the same rosa, rosa must keep her same number of children), I can rewrite my table if you don't see

Comment: It may be because of the Na values (should be NA), as DarrylG said. Could be?

Comment: yes I solved the beginning as he had told me

Comment: I think this should work as expected. If not, I am not getting what you want, sorry.